# CQWP image rendering as HTML for certain users

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have what I can only presume is a security related problem but comparing it to other site collections (which are pretty much a carbon copy of the site with a problem) there seems to be nothing different in regards to security. The attached image displays the div tags + html for what should actually be rendered but doesn't for a regular staff user, site collection admin sees the CQWP as the image which is correct and a staff user / student gets the div html.. any leads appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As silly as this sounds the actual problem was the fact that the itemstyle.xsl file was not 'checked in' and as such no user other than the site collection admin was seeing the html styles properly

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code?

you can try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Value" disable-output-escaping="no" />
```